# Checked out on master, brought changes to it and now cannot checkout back to branch

Tags: git, version-control, git-commit

```
git status
On branch master
Your branch is behind 'origin/master' by 10 commits, and can be fast-forwarded.
  (use "git pull" to update your local branch)

 

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
        modified:   Resources/Common/Ui-de.json
        modified:   Resources/Common/Ui-en.json
        modified:   Resources/Common/Ui-es.json
        modified:   Resources/Common/Ui-fr.json
        modified:   Resources/Common/Ui-nl.json

 

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

I was on my feature branch making changes, and saw these file changes which were modified by someone else. I committed them then checked out on master.

The issue is, on the master branch, these exact 5 changes still appear as uncommited changes, and now I cannot checkout to my other branches nor pull from origin as it's demanding me to commit changes first. However, I don't want to commit changes directly on master. And again, these changes aren't made by me.

I have tried stashing and reverting changes but both don't work, the files just stay there.

What exactly is happening here? I am thinking of just committing them on master without pushing so I can pull and checkout to other branches, and just never push those commits on master, but that doesn't seem like the best solution.

Comment: If they're uncommitted then they're not on master. The local master branch is also not up-to-date.

Comment: Look at the changes. It seems to be an end of line problem (that you should handle through the use of a `.gitattributes` file) that you should handle first.

Comment: Yes I think it's a CLRF changed to LF or vice-versa problem. Though in my gitattributes everything is already set to CLRF. I'm just wondering how come I cannot forcibly revert these changes/commits.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the fix!

```
git rm --cached -r .
git reset --hard
```

Comment: That's the brute force method (which is easy and simple and often therefore the one to use). Whenever you turn on the CRLF conversion features in Git, you can get into weird states like this.